# Does IntelliJ IDEA publish an Android app with one click?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play

On Android developer's page (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) there is a tutorial on publishing which says that an app has to be compiled as **an unsigned** app, a private key must be generated with `keytool` then signed with `jarsigner`.

How do we create an unsigned app with IntelliJ?

Alternatively, can we do all these steps via `Tools->Android->Export Signed Android Package`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

New IDEA versions have an option to generate unsigned APK in the Android Facet settings, Compiler tab:

[image: Generate unsigned APK]

However you don't need to do that if you use the Export Signed Android Package feature:

`Tools | Android | Export Signed Android Package` will generate the release version of your application signed with the release key and ready for Market.

You can also create a batch file that will sign the unsigned APK and configure it as an `External Tool` in IDEA so that you can generate it in one click or via keyboard shortcut (if you are OK with a batch file containing your keystore passwords in open text).

I use such script to generate the signed APK, upload it to a phone and start the main Activity to perform application testing, it has the following sequence of actions:

1. `jarsigner`
2. `zipalign`
3. `adb install`
4. `adb start`

---

**EDIT 2013/2/8:** The option to export a Signed APK is now under `Top Menu > Build > Generate Signed APK` (IntelliJ IDEA 12)

---

IDEA 12 has even better way to do it via artifact, configured like this:

[image: artifact]

Then use `Build` | **Build Artifacts** when you need to make a release version.

Comment: Thanks for a tip on batch files. I'm on my own computer so storing passwords in a text file is not a problem at all. However, I think that option `Export Signed Android Package` is far more convenient and for the time being I will use it. However, this tip on batch files is REALLY great and I will consider it seriously.

Comment: hey where this key store is stored . I can not find this key store.

Comment: @RiddhiShah this keystore file is created by you, so only you know where you've placed it. You can [find more details in Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Comment: I am new user of intellij idea so i don't know and I usually use this command for generate key. keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Riddhi\.android\debug.keystore -list -v

Comment: @RiddhiShah it's not IDE specific.

Comment: I need to create keystore new . can u give me steps or any hint then i can find or create certificate

Comment: @RiddhiShah I've already provided you a hint in the first reply: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Comment: there is no 'Android' option in my tools context menu

Answer (score 4):

Well you could modify the ant scripts slightly and have one target which builds a final signed APK. So that technically could be a one click build. Not sure about publishing, you may be restricted to using the web interface to upload and publish the app.

I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/publishing-your-app-to-the-android-market-a-noobs-guide/) on publish, it might be worth a read as I cover some of the building final releases and such

Comment: Thanks for a tip but I'm looking for the simplest way to get publish-ready APK and I think this built-in command is such way.