# Implementing ProGuard and testing outcome issues using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, proguard

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to develop for Android.

Now I want to introduce ProGuard. IntelliJ allows me to export signed or unsigned package with ProGuard - so this is cool. My problem is workflow very painful. I need to:

1. Export package.
2. Email package to device.
3. Install on device.
4. Watch for errors (and there is lot of issues)

I want to somehow implement one-click deployment to dev device of obfuscated package.
How do I do this?

Normally, I just click "Run" or "Debug" within IDE - but it doesn't use ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate it using a command line script and run it as an external tool from IntelliJ IDEA.

Check the [answer to this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5896741/104891).