# Compile signed APK and install it directly from IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

Does anyone know the way or the trick to **make signed APK and install it on device** from inside the IDE? Just like when we sign the app via debug key and then automatically install it on the device from the IDE.

When I test in-app and have to make multiple changes, it's slowing me down the fact that each time I have to install the APK by coping it onto the device or via console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an [artifact that will build a signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897970/104891).

Then create an [External Tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html) (batch file) that will upload the artifact to the device using `adb install` command. Optionally add the code to start the main activity. My `install.bat` looks like this:

```
adb install -r bin\ClockSync.apk
adb shell am start -n "ru.org.amip.ClockSync/ru.org.amip.ClockSync.view.Main"
```

Modify the commands if you want to deploy to the specific emulator/device.

[External tool configuration](http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/7779/fa1i.png) is pretty straightforward, just run the `bat` file.

Now you can create a [Run configuration](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/940/ginu.png) with **Before Launch** section set to build the signed APK artifact and start the external tool to deploy and run it.

**EDITED by sandalone**

This approach is for `IntelliJ IDEA` users. After you set it all up, just launch the app as usual `Shift` + `F10` and the app will be built as signed APK, installed on the device and started.

Since I am on Linux, I made the script `install.sh` with the following content

```
adb -s DEVICE_ID install -r ./com.package.name.apk
adb shell am start -n "com.package.name/com.package.name.MainActivity"
```

made it executable and this was it. Of course, the script should be located in the same place as APK - otherwise fix the path accordingly.